# Datadog capturing wrong IP on APM traces

Tags: datadog

Datadog is reporting that the requests made to my API are all coming from "172.20.xxx.xxx" which is technically true, but not what I actually need/expect...

I need datadog to get the real IP value in a custom header name "X-Indirect-Forwarded-For"... how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Set your `DD_TRACE_CLIENT_IP_HEADER` [environment variable](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/trace_collection/library_config/php/#environment-variable-configuration) to the name of the header you want to use.